# How to draw over second monitor with GDIPLUS

Tags: c++, visual-c++, drawing, gdi+, gdi

I'm want to draw some text and lines over the desktop.

I'm using gdiplus.h for print texts with the function DrawString.

But its only print text on a primary screen monitor.

If has in presentation mode, with 2 monitors I need to print text in a second monitor.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

int main() {

    HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(desktop); 

    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
    // Initialize GDI+
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    while (true)
    {

        HPEN newpen;
        LPPOINT point = NULL;
        newpen = CreatePen(PS_COSMETIC, 20, RGB(255, 0, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, newpen);
        MoveToEx(hdc, 1500, 500, point);
        LineTo(hdc, 1600, 550 ); 
        //this block works for draw line in second monitor

        TextOut(hdc, 1500, 300, TEXT("Text of text out"), 17); // this works too


    //But if I'm use gdiplus only print things on the primary screen
    Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);

    Pen      pen(Gdiplus::Color(0, 0, 255), 2);

    g.DrawLine(&pen, 1500, 0, 1700, 600);// dont work

    g.DrawLine(&pen, 0, 0, 1200, 600);//  work, but is in the primary screen

    FontFamily  fontFamily(L"Times New Roman");
    Font        font(&fontFamily, 24, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel);
    SolidBrush  brush(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));

    g.DrawString(TEXT("test of GDI+"), 13, &font, PointF(1600.0f, 300.0f), &brush); // dont work

    g.DrawString(TEXT("test of GDI+"), 13, &font, PointF(500.0f, 300.0f), &brush); // work, but is in the primary screen
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is surprisingly difficult.  The help for [GetWindowDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does warn us it only applies to the primary display monitor (which is clearly only half true, because the regular GDI bits in your example do work):

> To get the device context for other display monitors, use the
>   EnumDisplayMonitors and CreateDC functions.

That's not much of a hint, but I suppose something along the lines of this working example (based on your code) is intended:

```C++
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace Gdiplus;

#pragma comment (lib,"Gdiplus.lib")

BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    MONITORINFOEXW info;
    info.cbSize = sizeof(info);
    ::GetMonitorInfoW(hMonitor, &info);

    HDC hdc = ::CreateDCW(NULL, info.szDevice, NULL, NULL);

    {
        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);

        FontFamily  fontFamily(L"Times New Roman");
        Font        font(&fontFamily, 24, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel);
        SolidBrush  brush(Color(255, 0, 0, 255));

        graphics.DrawString(
                    info.szDevice,
                    wcslen(info.szDevice),
                    &font,
                    PointF(0.0f, 0.0f),
                    &brush);
    }

    ::DeleteDC(hdc);

    return TRUE;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    ULONG_PTR m_gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    while (true)
    {
        ::EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MonitorEnumProc, NULL);
    }

    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(m_gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```